# How to get Sugested People, Documents and Sites to follow in Sharepoint online using REST

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, jquery, rest

I know we can use

```
http://<siteCollection>/<site>/_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getmysuggestions
```

API but I am unable to get the Data

Comment: Are you getting an error or you are getting empty result xml?

Comment: I need the get method associated with it using which I can get the data

Comment: [this](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html) blog explains all available properties you can query

Comment: it is for user profile prpoerties, I want for the suggested documents, sites and people to follow. You have IsFOllowed there but you dont have SuggestFOllowed. Correct me if I am wrong